# SQL Query to replace record of table with another

Tags: sql

The following code produces an error:

```
select lastname, firstname, workphone, homephone 
from members if (workphone is null) then workphone = homephone;
```

I am trying to select the `lastnames`, `firstnames` and thee phone numbers from a table named `members`. If a members' `workphone is null` I need to replace it with the `homephone`.

I would be more than happy to clarify if need be.

Comment: ***WHAT*** database? SQL is just the query language....

Comment: I have loaded the lyric database

Comment: Why not just pull it down and do the mapping client-side?

Comment: Are you trying to update the database or query some date (and return the homephone if a work phone does not exist)?

Comment: No updates are necessary. Simple output suffices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select lastname, firstname, 
case when (workphone is null) then homephone  else workphone end as workphone 
, homephone 
from members;
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Pavlov. Your updated answer is in fact the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `COALESCE` function, which returns the first not null argument it's given:

```
SELECT lastname, firstname, homephone, COALESCE(workphone, homephone) AS workphone
FROM   members
```